# Optimising large string on browser on load time

Tags: javascript

I have created a function which will dynamically append xml content to a string variable on browser on load time . However, when the string becomes enormous , it will result in memory loss.
I have created a function which enable user to download as xls format.

For an example,

//This has 1k records which are translated as xml content that is stored in uri variable
on browser. We are able to download xls file with no issue

```
//String length e.g 20k
var workbookXML = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,.......<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-.application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>.........'
```

now when im appending high volume of data that are translated into xml content , this will result the browser to stop and prompt Memory loss issue on browser

```
//String length e.g 20million
var workbookXML = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,.......<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-.application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>.........'
```

I have look into writableStream but this will result the same as this will be on browser. . What are best approaches in this use cases to resolve big data into a single string variable on browser?

Should i convert string into binary, bytes before exporting as xls format ?

```
        var excel_blob = new Blob([workbookXML], { type: 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        var link = document.createElement("A");
        link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(excel_blob)
        link.download = "BigData" + ".xls";
        link.target = '_blank';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how your browser can't handle a 20-40MB string... If there are memory issues I would rather try to seek the problem in something else than that string. I guess you would anyway have trouble with data uri since browsers limit the lenght of the uri (eg. 2MB for chromium based, and 80MB for webkit like Safari). I know that moz (Firefox) and blink (Opera) do not limit it but never tried btw

Comment: You could opt to a [gzip compressed solution (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456694/how-to-download-gzip-compressed-file-generated-from-string-with-client-sided-jav) (probably it will need webpack)

Answer (score 1):

> What are best approaches in this use cases to resolve big data into a single string variable on browser?

Simple: don't.

It looks like you're trying to download files? There already is a tried and true protocol to download files, which is using a get request to get back a file (or multiple files, if your browser supports it).

There's absolutely no need to store the entire file in html in a base64 string, append it to your DOM as an element, click it to initiate the download and remove it. That's just insanity.